# How to access this type of PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

how i can access this type of php array? for example i want to get the **time value** from every array inside the data array?

(every array start with a different name and it always change it can be 'AK7FJAIEVBCA6' or 'PNAYN6JEB9VSJ2' etc..)

```
Array (
    [test] => 1
    [data] => Array (
        [Changing_value1] => Array (
        [now] => 1
        [time] => 10000
        )
        [Changing_value2] => Array (
        [now] => 1
        [time] => 10000
        )
        [Changing_value3] => Array (
        [now] => 1
        [time] => 10000
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array['data'][0]['time']
```

or to iterate it

```
foreach($array['data'] as $data) {
   $time = $data['time'];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but this will not work because to access 'time' you must access the array containing this value (Changing_value), this value always change and i don't know how i can access it

Comment: So if you want to go through all, just iterate like @bali182 or for a single value use `$array['data']['Changing_value1']['time']` putting the index of the `Changing_value` you need to access

Comment: And what do you want to do with the values? Iterate them in a loop? collect them in another array?

Comment: @Kypros the changing value is value that i don't know because it always change it can be 'AI4L30VX49B', bali182 i want to collect it to another array but i know how to do that i just don't know how i can access the array

Comment: So how do you wanna access it? Get one or get all times?

Comment: @Kypros i want to get all the 'time' value

Comment: So why not use the `foreach()` loop as @bali182 has already given you?